How to receive file from Postman or Next.js with POST method
I want to send a file as image or pdf. While I am using Postman, I make POST method and body type is form-data. Liike this screenshot:
. But I can't receive any body in Express. My Node.js code is like:

And output is like that:

I tried multer and multipart libraries, but it doesn't work.
How can I solve this problem?

Have you by any chance tried using Body-Parser? It could resolve an issue you may have, if that still does not work. You could try looking at Multer Docs, I hope this helps!

Yes I added. Not I checked again my codes. I forgot adding multer.diskStorage() method. That's why it doesn't work. I solve the problem. Thanks a lot care about my problem :)
